# Executing MDX expressions on SSAS with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssas, mdx

We are experimenting with setting up a nodejs express app on a Windows server and consume OLAP data from our OLAP cubes.

1. Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server Analysis Service and
   execute MDX expressions with nodejs? If so, what npm packages/drivers are
   needed?
2. Is it possible to query/get cube metadata in the environment I mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: Found out that ODBC doesn't work to connect to SSAS. I'll update if I come across any solutions. https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/issues/132

Comment: Use a stored procedure that embeds a call (through linked server) to ssas by providing an mdx query :-) then via odbc you simply call the stored procedure. It's a good workaround

Comment: could you find any solution ?